# how to insert values from listbox to datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, listbox

In my code I have 2 listboxes and 1 datagridview.I want to get listbox1 data to datagridview1 column0 and listbox2 data to datagridview column1?

```
        foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value = item;
                dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1].Value = listBox2.Items; 
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
listBox1.Items.Add("1");
listBox1.Items.Add("2");
listBox1.Items.Add("3");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("First","First");

foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    int idx = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

    dataGridView1.Rows[idx].Cells["First"].Value = item;

}
```

Sample output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`item` represents an item stored in the ListBox. So if you'd like to grab the value of the selected one and show it in the datagrid then:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value = listBox1.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
```

it takes the first selected item's value into grid.

Answer (score 0):

Create a datattable with the required columns and bind it to gridview.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Column1",typeof(datatype));//column 0
dt.Columns.Add("Column2",typeof(datattype));//column 1    
if(ListBox1.Items.Count == ListBox2.Items.Count)
{
for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(ListBox1.Items[i].Text, ListBox2.Items[i].Text);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.DataBind();
}
```